# How would one go about including a.dll description / company information?

Tags: c++, dll, field-description

So, over the last few years I've noticed that branded dynamic link libraries ( in most cases ) will include a description and or company name to their assembly. How would one go about including this? It's fairly common, yet It's nearly impossible to find information on. All of my books which I've learned from never have explained the process to me.

Anyone know if it's possible without a license you obtain.

I've attempted to look into this from a few other posts. Only thing I could find was about C#.

Here's an example: http://prntscr.com/ndyokr

Comment: You put it in a VERSIONINFO resource and add it to your app or DLL with a resource editor.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I figured it out. It's a resource. I didn't know until I looked over some VS_VERSION_INFO. 
You can add a new listed version to your project. Doing so will allow custom file information!